# Is there any way to run a foreground service in react native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, foreground-service

I've been doing a few searches on google trying to find a way to run foreground services in react native but I haven't found much about it.

Is anyone aware of how to accomplish this?
This is what I mean by foreground service: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground

Answer (score 0):

I have an example React Native Foreground Service app [here](https://github.com/rgstephens/ForegroundTest).  In this example, I'm doing a Bluetooth scan every 10 seconds and attempting to run a Foreground Service so that the scans will continue even if the app isn't in the foreground.

You can remove the call in `index.js` that does the BLE scan and you'll have a simple RN Foreground Service example.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: for some reason the link isn't working anymore.[This](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@supersami/rn-foreground-service)  is the good link as pointed out by DAN.

Here's a package [react-native-foreground-service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@supersami/react-native-foreground-service) i found, while I was dealing with the same issue.

Comment: I created that above service and the correct link for it is here.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@supersami/rn-foreground-service